# Redirect to a div overlay on same page after submitting form in HTML

Tags: php, html, css, forms

I have a PHP page that contains more than one forms, it should redirect the first form to another form on the same page.

problem is that when submitting the form values it refreshes the page nothing else and also it redirects to the same page but not to another form on which i want to redirect.

it is a form-chaining in which the next form values are dependent on the previous form submission like questionnaires.

can anybody please tell me how it is possible.

Comment: It´s called javascript. Php gets executed once, if you submit a form it refreshes the page.

Comment: Basically you need to search for multi-step php forms or wizard-like forms. You'll pass a variable `?step=1` in the URL to know where you are and increase it with every form submit. Here's a [demo](http://codingcyber.com/creating-multistep-form-processing-using-php-228/)

Comment: @Miro: Thanks, I think it's quite beneficial for me

Comment: @Doomenik: I can better understand what you are saying actually, but instead of PHP I am redirecting the form using javascript, but still it didn't work. by the way thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Instead of redirection I recommend working with html/js as page file and then only call php via ajax to retrieve the informations like the next form values. Here is a little example of the principe https://www.formget.com/form-submission-using-ajax-php-and-javascript/

Comment: @Doomenik: Thanks, could you please tell me, can we give same id or same name to more than one submit button

Comment: Its not recommended to give them the same id, its possible but bad practice. Instead provide them the same class.

Comment: Lets say you have a questionarie, the best practice would it to have only 1 form. After submitting you call via ajax a php file which returns you the next questions. Inside your ajax result you can change your actual form and fill it with the next questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use ajax for form submitting means there is no need of page refresh. But if you are not using ajax and page will refresh means,before submitting the form store the current **scroll position** in a **session** variable.on page load check that session variable is set ,if so means scroll to the position after page load and you can delete the session variable based on your logic